# Display subcategories of main category in sidebar in magento

Tags: php, magento, categories

I have some `categories` and their `subcategories` as below:

```
Mobile
    Nokia
    Samsung
    Micromax
Television
    LG
    Panasonic
    Philips
Laptop
    Acer
    Dell
```

When I click the `category` **Mobile**, in `right side bar` all `categories and subcategories are displayed`.But I need to display `subcategories` of **Mobile** only. That is **Nokia, Samsung,Micromax** only.

How can I manage this? Which file handle this operation? I can't find the required file also.

Please help me...My **magento version is 1.9.0.1**

**EDIT**

In `display settings` of category I set `Is anchor` to **YES** then in `right side bar all categories are displayed`. If I set **NO** `the subcategories only displayed in left side bar`. `I need right side bar because it contain some filter options too`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved...

What I am here using is `layered navigation`.

To display `layered navigation` what I did is: In `Catalog > Manage Categories > (Category name) > Display settings` change `Is Anchor` to **Yes**.

Then,

In `app\design\frontend[template][template]\layout\catalog.xml` in *Category layered navigation layout* section,

I change

```
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav1" before="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml"/>
```

to

```
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav1" before="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
```

And now its working as desired....

Answer (score 0):

You can use following extension and it is free.

http://www.manadev.com/advanced-layered-navigation-ce

You can check demo from their website.

Answer (score 0):

In category settings, set category "mobile" as an anchor category.  This will lock the customer into the experience of shopping by mobile devices.

Comment: In display settings of category I set Is anchor to YES then in right side bar all categories are displayed. If I set NO the subcategories only displayed in left side bar. I need right side bar because it contain some filter options too.